# Dúvida com search em array

Tags: php, array

minha dúvida é a seguinte: Como faço para realizar busca em uma chave e retornar seu valor?

Ex.

```
$contagem = array('metodologia' => '1','facilidade' => '10')
```

gostaria de buscar por facilidade e retornar o valor 10.

Agradecido!

Comment: `$contagem['facilidade']` acessa o valor `'10'`. É isso que você quer?

Comment: Depois do comentário na resposta abaixo, me parece que o que você quer é `$contagem[$termo_pesquisado]`. Queira [edit] a pergunta e explicar melhor o problema, pois para o que você perguntou, a resposta dada está perfeita.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o nome da variavel seguido pelo campo que deseja pegar, por exemplo.

```
$contagem['facilidade']
```

Comment: Na verdade essa busca farei com uma variável passada na função.  esse param que preciso localizar, nem sempre ele estará no array. Fiz com foreach e pregmatch mas ficou inviável, o array tem um pouco mais que 2k de registro e o param em torno de 6k de registro. Já precisei reiniciar o serviço do apache por conta disso.

Comment: Me surge a ideia de fazer um  search na key, se for verdadeiro ele busca o valor dessa forma, seria a melhor solução?

Comment: Basta usar `if isset($contagem[$strComNomeDoCampo]) == true` usar o valor...

Comment: Você pode usar a função [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-key-exists.php) ou [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php) para verificar se a chave existe no array.